# how can i connect from node.js to sql DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssms

i tried the following code:

```
const config = {
server: 'localhost',
database: 'MyDB',
user: *userName*,
password: *password*

const dbPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, err => {
 if (err)
   console.log(err)
 else
   console.log("success")
})
```

i created on the SSMS a user and a login, and did logged in with it to make sure it works. i changed the authentication from windows to SQL server. what am i missing?

I keep get this error message:

> Login failed for user *'userNamr'.*,
>
> Code: 'ELOGIN'

Comment: Have you checked the logs on SQL Server? Can you see the connection attempt there, and if so, what do the logs say is the reason the login was rejected?

Comment: Can you please print `err` in else part. So that we can check.

Comment: what is the full error, any error code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have entered a wrong username or a user that does not exist but here is the demonstration how you can connect node.js to sql.

PS: make sure you have npm install and proper module for the db engine.

```
const pg = require("pg"); //replace "pg" with whatever engine you are using such as mssql

const connectionString = {
      user: 'username',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'testdb',
      password: 'mypass',
      port: 5432,
    };

const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    client.query(
        'SELECT * from student;'
        ).then(
          res => {
        console.log(res.rows);
    }).finally(() => client.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the package you are [using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).In that case, I believe you are missing the connect method which as taken from the docs.Also ELOGIN err comes when login fails

```
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: '...'
})

pool.connect(err => {
    // ...
})
```